# Android: Searching in list vs searching using DAO

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am fetching a list of objects from my DAO, this list contains roughly 500 objects. Sample structure of object:

```
data class Foo(
val a: String,
val b: String,
val c: String,
val d: String,
val e: String,
)
```

I am fetching the list using `dao.getAllFoo()`, and I am storing this list in a global variable.

I have another usecase in the same viewmodel where I need to filter around 10 items from this list of 500 Foo objects on the basis of field a.

What should be the ideal way to do it? Should I traverse this stored list or should I use the DAO method `dao.getFooBasedOnA(a: String)` to construct the new list?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .filter method in the global list